# Are memcached entries saved by the Danga client compatible with the Spy client?

Tags: java, memcached, compatibility, spy

After saving a String value into memcached using the Danga client, I attempted to get the entry  using the Spy client.  The two String values are not the same.  The Danga client retrieves a string with an additional empty char prepended to the string, therefore violating the equality condition.

> Danga
> t,e,s,t,s,t,r,i,n,g
>
> Spy
> ,t,e,s,t,s,t,r,i,n,g

I also attempted to save a serialized Map using the Danga client and get the Map using the Spy client.  The Spy client is able to only get a String form of the Map.  The string contains binary values.

Has anyone been able to get a Danga client-saved memcached entry correctly using the Spy client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, look at the [transcoders](http://dustin.github.com/java-memcached-client/apidocs/net/spy/memcached/transcoders/package-summary.html) for more information of how things get encoded on the network.

Specifically, I have [WhalinTranscoder](http://dustin.github.com/java-memcached-client/apidocs/net/spy/memcached/transcoders/WhalinTranscoder.html) for the recent versions and [WhalinV1Transcoder](http://dustin.github.com/java-memcached-client/apidocs/net/spy/memcached/transcoders/WhalinV1Transcoder.html) for dealing with older versions.

You can use a [ConnectionFactoryBuilder](http://dustin.github.com/java-memcached-client/apidocs/net/spy/memcached/ConnectionFactoryBuilder.html) to configure your transcoder instance to get different behaviors.